# Linq to Excel issues

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I mapped out all the columns in my excel, then i try and read the worksheet using this

```
var file = theFile.Worksheet<myClass>("worksheetTitle").OrderBy(p => p.columnHeader).ToList();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E57): The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add.  Try inserting or pasting less data.
   at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor.GetDataResults(SqlParts sql, QueryModel queryModel)
   at LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryExecutor.ExecuteCollection[T](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo.ExecuteCollectionQueryModel[T](QueryModel queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData.StreamedSequenceInfo.ExecuteQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel, IQueryExecutor executor)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryModel.Execute(IQueryExecutor executor)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryProviderBase.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: did you try to google error?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213841/ ?

Comment: It sounds like perhaps your mapping is incorrect, or perhaps you have some bad data in your worksheet.  Try `var file = theFile.Worksheet<myClass>("worksheetTitle").Take(1).ToList();` and see if you still get the error (eliminating order, and only taking the first record)

Comment: that eliminated the error, but I need all the fields and records on that worksheet? Any work around?

Comment: @RobertMcKee can't i sort the worksheet and take just the first two row?

Comment: If it was me, I would change the Take until I got the error, then look at that row in the worksheet and see what the difference is.

Comment: I think it's because i have too many rows, I'm not sure what the limit is on for linq but i believe that is the problem. Also linq for some reason does not like the title of worksheets such as spacing or capital letters.

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock did any of your excel column has charachters more than 255 or something..its the issue with Oledb...

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. some had more than 255. Was wondering if there was any way around it .

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock only work around is reordering the row..try to put one of the row having 255 character as first row and try..see my answer below..i got this during my MVC project :( it took 1 week to found the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is problem with the Excel ODBC driver which can often be worked around by reordering the records in the spreadsheet..
The Excel ODBC driver has to make an assumption about the data type for a given column. The driver does this by reading ahead 8 records and looking at the data found. It then makes a decision about the data type based upon what it has read. Problems occur when the assumption about data type is proven wrong by subsequent records.
A column in an Excel spreadsheet has a column in it which contains string data. The first 8 records contain short strings. The Excel ODBC driver reads this data and assumes that a short string data type will be appropriate for this column. If a subsequent record contains a longer string. The data type may prove inappropriate and unable to store the longer string and the error willraised by the Excel ODBC driver. Moving the record with the long string to the beginning of the dataset will allow the Excel ODBC to select a more appropriate data type for the column which will apply to all records in the spreadsheet.

In all cases the technique is to arrange the order of the records such that the Excel ODBC driver is allowed to make the correct selection of data type.

Comment: r u using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for accesing the excel properties in c#

Comment: I tried, but I have not had any success in opening the file or changing the file.

Comment: Yup, unless you have another solution